# Using shell script, how do I put numbers in formats like 000?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have large number of files which have file names in the format of XXX_name_YYY.out with YYY and YYY being numbers. I want to use a loop to move all files starting with XXX_name to a folder with the name 'XXX_name'. I am very new to shell scripting and only code a bit in C.

I would do something like this but the format of the numbers does not match the numbers in the file names.

```
c=1
while[c -le 100]
do
    d=1
    mkdir "$c"_name
    while[d - le 100]
    do
        mv "$c"_name_"$d".out "$c"_name/"$c"_name_"$d".out
        (( d++ ))
    done

    (( c++ ))
done
```

Comment: you can probably try the curly expansion(if your bash supports it): for c in {000..099}; do echo "$c"; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for FILE in [0-9][0-9][0-9]_name_[0-9][0-9][0-9].out; do
    DIR=${FILE%_*.out}
    [[ -d $DIR ]] || mkdir "$DIR" && echo mv "$FILE" $DIR/"
done
```

Remove `echo` when you're sure it works already.

Comment: This may or may not work depending on the files in the directory.  The poster specified that unknown values on either side are *numbers*, but using `?` will match anything.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Yes I considered that. Although I find that unlikely. So I chose to just give a simpler example than using extended pathname expansions.... Although come to think of it I think wouldn't need the extended version. I'll do an update.